# What is wrong with this string copy using pointers code?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to copy a string using character pointers. I have tried this code but it prints nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *ptr1 = "madhava";
    char *ptr2 = new char[strlen(ptr1)+1]; //get the memory
    while(*ptr1){
        *ptr2 = *ptr1;
        ptr2++;
        ptr1++;
    }
    *ptr2 = '\0';
    printf("%s",ptr2); //print the target
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `ptr2` -- where des it point -- at the time of printing? The line directly above the `printf` might give you a clue. `:)`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @MOehm. Are you suggesting to have me a temporary pointer to store the ptr2 before changing?

Comment: As a side comment, a `new` without a matching `delete` is a memory leak. For that, however, you need a valid pointer to the allocated memory..

Comment: Yes, either that or create a "working pointer" for the copying or put allocating and copying into a separate function, so that the working pointers are local variables.

Comment: "What is wrong with this string copy using pointers code" as a code review: it uses pointers, `new`, and `strlen`. `std::string str1 = "madhava"; auto str2 = str1; std::cout << str2;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by the time you try and print the string, `ptr2` points to the end of it. Try making a copy of that pointer and traversing the string with it.

```
    char *ptr2 = new char[strlen(ptr1)+1];
    char *ptr3 = ptr2; // create a copy of the pointer and work with that
    while(*ptr1){
        *ptr3 = *ptr1;
        ptr3++;
        ptr1++;
    }
    *ptr3 = '\0';
    printf("%s",ptr2);
    delete[] ptr2;
    // ... and then null out ptr2 or ptr3 if needed
```

You should consider using `std::string` instead of manually doing this yourself.

Comment: yes, it works @Travis. so  I understood as it points to the '\0', it points nothing, and to get this right, we need a temp pointer. Thank you very much

Comment: Precisely, you understand what's happening.

Comment: `delete ptr2;` -- This is the wrong form of delete.  It should be `delete []`

Comment: Fixed. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *ptr1 = "madhava";
    char *ptr2 = new char[strlen(ptr1)+1]; //get the memory
    char *ptr3=ptr2; //create new pointer which points to ptr2
    while(*ptr1){
        *ptr2 = *ptr1;
        ptr2++;
        ptr1++;
    }

    *ptr2 = '\0';
    printf("%s",ptr3); //print the target // change ptr2 to ptr3
    return 0;
}
```

The problem in your code is ptr2 is pointing to the end of the string.